# Wait for ajax requests in array to be completed

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm trying to iterate through the ID's (containing an URL) of checked checkboxes. With each checkbox, it generates an AJAX-get which does a certain action on the database. This is working, however not all AJAX-gets seem to be executed (the redirect gets executed too fast).

As adviced, I've tried to make use of '$.when.apply', however, this doesn't seem to be working. I get a 'missing ) after argument list', most certainly generated in the part where I'm pushing the ajax-get.

Is this the right way or should I try another method?

```
$("#marksolved").click(function () {
    var ajaxrequests = [];

    // Loop through checkboxes.
    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        // Each id of a checkbox contains an URL.
        var markurl = $(this).attr('id');

        // Do the request.
        ajaxrequests.push($.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: markurl,
            cache: false
        });
    });

    // Check if all requests have completed.
    $.when.apply($, ajaxrequests).then(function () {
        // All requests have completed. An ajax-redirect will eventually take place too fast...
        alert('All actions done!');

    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have a known number of AJAX requests to complete?

Comment: yes, that is the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I get a 'missing ) after argument list', most certainly generated in the part where I'm pushing the ajax-get.*

```
    ajaxrequests.push($.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: markurl,
        cache: false
    });
```

should be:

```
    ajaxrequests.push($.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: markurl,
        cache: false
    }));
```

It's missing a `)`, like the error says.

Side note: It would probably be far more efficient to combine all of your requests into one batch request instead of having one request for each checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking over it several times.

Comment: I find entering code into jsfiddle.net and hitting the "TidyUp" and "JSHint" buttons to be very helpful in finding syntax errors quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Jason!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) to have an event raised when all ajax requests have ended, or `$.ajaxComplete()` for when all requests have completed.

Comment: his deferred usage should have the same effect, once the typo is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the ajax async option to false

```
$.ajax({
    method:'GET',
    url: markurl,
    cache:false,
    async: false
});
```

Comment: Is this as good as the code I posted above? It would indeed be easy to just nest the ajax in the checkbox iteration...

Comment: This would cause a HUGE delay, larger and larger based on how many requests are being sent. However, it would technically solve the problem, not without causing it's own problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many ajax requests you are making, you could do something like this:

```
var ajax_count = 0;
var ajax_checker;
var ajax_n = 3;
$('input:checked').each(function() {
  ...
  ajaxrequests.push($.ajax({
    method:'GET',
    url: markurl,
    cache: false,
    success: function(){ ajax_count++; }
  });
}

// Check if all requests have completed.
function ajax_complete() {
  if (ajax_count >= ajax_n) {
    clearInterval(ajax_checker);
    //continue working
    alert('All actions done!');
  }
}

ajax_checker = setInterval(function() {ajax_complete();}, 50);
```

Comment: Why not just use `$.ajaxStop()`?

Comment: @xdumaine possibly because I never heard of it until now =)

Comment: @xdumaine: I tried, but the redirect seems to be executed after each ajax-get in the iteration...

Comment: Using jQuery deferred objects is a far more elegant way of solving this problem.